# 1995 Integra ABS : What is the most common failure mode?

Tags: troubleshooting, abs, bleeding, integra

The ABS red dashboard indicator is lit.   The ABS module was [bled with brake fluid per youTube instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yO0cr9cVf0U) to remove air from the system.  After sending 32+ ounces through the system, the air bubbles persisted.  The electric fluid pump seemed to work in spurts.

Before purchasing a [replacement ABS Module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/116036165901), I'd like to be more confident that the purchase will solve the problem.

1. Is the problem in the ABS module?
2. What is the most common failure mode for ABS modules?

If you have experience with this issue, please indicate this in your reply.  Bonus if the experience is with an Intega or  Civic.   Thanks!

Comment: Is the car OBD I or II? Can you pull codes?

Comment: Good questions.   IIRC Google indicated it is NOT OBD2: which was mandated for 1996.  Is this the procedure to pull codes? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGlPVybVccg&t=10s

Comment: That looks correct for pulling codes.